# Setting euler rotates camera, but setting quaternion doesn't

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, camera

I was trying to make a camera look at a certain object. I used the following code:

```
diff = objs[2].location - objs[0].location
rot_quat = diff.to_track_quat('-Z','Y')
```

Then, if I try to set the rotation using quaternion - it does not work.

```
camera.rotation_quaternion = rot_quat
```

But, when I try euler rotations - it works perfectly.

```
camera.rotation_euler = rot_quat.to_euler()
```

It seems weird to me that this should happen. Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with eulers because [`rotation_mode`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=object#bpy.types.Object.rotation_mode) is set to `XYZ` by default.

Either change it to `QUATERNION` or modify [`matrix_basis`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=object#bpy.types.Object.matrix_basis) (or some of the other matrix attributes). You can easily convert any quaternion to a matrix using its method [`to_matrix`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_1/mathutils.html?highlight=quaternion.to_matrix#mathutils.Quaternion.to_matrix) and resize it with [`to_4x4`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_1/mathutils.html?highlight=quaternion.to_matrix#mathutils.Matrix.to_4x4)

I.e.

```
mat = q.to_matrix().to_4x4()
mat.translation = cam.location
cam.matrix_basis = mat
```